# EF6 Setting Connection String at runtime with parameterless connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a custom DbContext class and reading connection string from a text file and a DbContext connection string at runtime.Such as ;

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1063:ImplementIDisposableCorrectly")]
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class ASDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ASUser, ASRole, int, ASUserLogin, ASUserRole, ASUserClaim>, IDbContext
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringManager _connectionStringManager;

    public ASDbContext(IDatabaseInitializer<ASDbContext> dbInitializer,
        IDbCommandInterceptor dbCommandInterceptor,
        IConnectionStringManager connectionStringManager) : base() 
    {
        this._connectionStringManager = connectionStringManager;

        if (!_connectionStringManager.CheckIfConnectionStringExists())
        {
            return;
        }
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = _connectionStringManager.ReadConnectionString().;
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(dbInitializer);
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        DbInterception.Add(dbCommandInterceptor);
    }
     //...                       
}
```

This works with Sql Server.However, it doesn't work with mysql. Following line throws exception ;

```
 this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = _connectionStringManager.ReadConnectionString().ConnectionString;
```

> [ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
>      System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +1739
>      System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +191
>      System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +136
>      System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value) +87
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connStr) +81
>      MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +382
>      MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +38
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +398
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection() +16

The workaround I've come up with is , passing a dummy connection string to constructor of base DbContext class. Such as ;

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1063:ImplementIDisposableCorrectly")]
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public partial class ASDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ASUser, ASRole, int, ASUserLogin, ASUserRole, ASUserClaim>, IDbContext
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringManager _connectionStringManager;

    // Passing "S=;" as connection string is a dirty workaround
    public ASDbContext(IDatabaseInitializer<ASDbContext> dbInitializer,
        IDbCommandInterceptor dbCommandInterceptor,
        IConnectionStringManager connectionStringManager) : base("S=;") 
    {
        this._connectionStringManager = connectionStringManager;

        if (!_connectionStringManager.CheckIfConnectionStringExists())
        {
            return;
        }
        this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = _connectionStringManager.ReadConnectionString().;
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(dbInitializer);
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        DbInterception.Add(dbCommandInterceptor);
    }
     //...                       
}
```

Although,it works i don't like to fix the problem with a dirty workaround like passing dummy connection string. 
Is there another way to fix this error?